# Getting accessibility issue with AG-Grid React checkbox column

Tags: accessibility, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, uiaccessibility

Today I generated accessibility report of a react application using ARC Toolkit plugin (Download Url - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-toolkit/chdkkkccnlfncngelccgbgfmjebmkmce?hl=en) and **received 26 Errors** with error message **Duplicate labels used**.

Description of error: The form contains multiple  elements with the same text content.

I observed that I am getting this accessibility issue due to a Ag-Grid checkbox column. Each row of this column has a checkbox, for example if we have 26 rows in grid then this column will contain 26 checkbox.
The root cause of this error message is, Ag-grid is adding same **aria-label="Press Space to toggle all rows selection (unchecked)"** with every checkbox created in that column.

I tried to find working solution of this issue but no luck. Please help me to find a solution of this accessibility issue.

Note: Due to organization security/restriction. I can not share the screenshots of error message.

Comment: We cannot help you if you cannot share your code or even the error message. Hire someone who your organization is willing to do work with.

Comment: Tiny detail: On their [live demo](https://www.ag-grid.com/), the checkboxes’ labels are all “Press Space to toggle row selection (unchecked)”, not the one you posted.
Any way, these texts seem very weird, so I’m wondering whether they tested with screen reader users or at least with sr. They already announce the checked status and how to change that.

Comment: [“If there is a need to customise these labels, this could be achieved by changing the localisation variables”](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/accessibility/#customising-aria-labels) this first looked like a viable work-around, but since no variable seems to be passed to the string, you cannot render them unique. There doesn’t seem an option to simply remove them, either, because the grid’s structure usually suffices to provide unique labels for contained inputs.

Comment: Thank you for you reply @Andy. I also observed the same as aria-label is static so it will be same for all checkbox. So now I am modifying the aria-label text after DOM load to make it unique.

Comment: I entirely removing the label solving the issue, or causing another error from axe?

Comment: If entirely removing aria-label from checkbox input field then getting a new error "Input has no accessible name".

Comment: @Andy. How did u manipulate the DOM after grid render. I am stuck in a similar issue for accessbility. I want to change the name of the aria attribute but unable to do so . Could u share some code sample here.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that aria-label is static so it will be same for all checkbox, Ag-grid is not providing any way to make it dynamic for all checkbox input fields. So now I modified the aria-label text after DOM load to make it unique.

Also removing aria-label entirely from checkbox input field throwing a new error "Input has no accessible name". So modifying the aria-label text is better choice.